# Google cloud function ssh: not found

Tags: google-cloud-functions

This cloud function works fine with Go runtime 1.16

```
// Package p contains an HTTP Cloud Function.
package p

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os/exec"
    "fmt"
)

// HelloWorld prints the JSON encoded "message" field in the body
// of the request or "Hello, World!" if there isn't one.
func HelloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    cmd := exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", fmt.Sprintf("ssh -v %s", "localhost"))
    stdout, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    log.Printf(string(stdout))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

I see this output

```
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

However it doesn't work in case I use Go runtime v1.18 or higher.

```
/bin/bash: line 1: ssh: command not found
```

I can't use v1.16 for my real function because it's not compilable. Is it possible to turn on ssh on target OS somehow?

```
Build failed: # golang.org/x/sys/unix
/layers/google.go.functions-framework/gopath/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.8.0/unix/syscall.go:83:16: undefined: unsafe.Slice
/layers/google.go.functions-framework/gopath/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.8.0/unix/syscall_linux.go:1018:20: undefined: unsafe.Slice
/layers/google.go.functions-framework/gopath/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.8.0/unix/syscall_linux.go:2297:9: undefined: unsafe.Slice
/layers/google.go.functions-framework/gopath/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.8.0/unix/syscall_unix.go:118:7: undefined: unsafe.Slice
/layers/google.go.functions-framework/gopath/pkg/mod/golang.org/x/sys@v0.8.0/unix/sysvshm_unix.go:33:7: undefined: unsafe.Slice
note: module requires Go 1.17; Error ID: 6fba28bd
```

Comment: Why do you need to ssh to localhost on a serverless function that doesn't execute on servers that run indefinitely?  There is nothing in the GCF docs that suggest this is a supported (or useful) feature.  You might want to read through the [documentation on execution environment](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/execution-environment) to see what GCF guarantees you.  An ssh exe is not among them.

Comment: In addition to Doug's comment, SSH is a fairly large application that must be installed and configurated. That is not possible in Cloud Functions. SSH uses a different protocol which Cloud Functions does not support without tunneling. SSH requires persistent connections whereas Cloud Functions provides an entry point for calling a function (small piece of code).

Comment: @DougStevenson it's just example.

Comment: @JohnHanley ssh worked fine in google cloud functions so it is strange to exclude this functionality in newer runtimes.

Comment: The thing is that ssh was never a documented, guaranteed part of the runtime in the first place.  It (among probably many other things) were likely removed to save space and increase security. If you absolutely need ssh, then maybe Cloud Functions isn't the right product for your needs.  You can control the image that gets deployed if you use something like Cloud Run or Compute Engine.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a community wiki so that others can benefit from it.

---

As mentioned by @Doug Stevenson:

> The thing is that ssh was never a documented, guaranteed part of the runtime in the first place. It (among probably many other things) were likely removed to save space and increase security. If you absolutely need ssh, then maybe Cloud Functions isn't the right product for your needs. You can control the image that gets deployed if you use something like Cloud Run or Compute Engine.

And mentioned by @John Hanley:

> In addition to Doug's comment, SSH is a fairly large application that must be installed and configurated. That is not possible in Cloud Functions. SSH uses a different protocol which Cloud Functions does not support without tunneling. SSH requires persistent connections whereas Cloud Functions provides an entry point for calling a function (small piece of code).

---

You may also check Compute Engine Documentation:

- [Configure apps to use SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/service-account-ssh)